# Tumblr pages' sidebars

Tags: html, css, web, blogs, tumblr

I am designing a tumblr blog with a right side bar where the facebook and twitter buttons and links to subpages are shown. To this end i have defined a custom layout which is correctly depicted in the blog's first page. The problem is with sub-pages where the layout is correctly depicted but the side bar is empty. I would like instead to show, in the sub-pages' side bar, the same contents which are defined in my blog's custom layout and shown in the first page.

Comment: What kind of content? Can you show us what you're done at this point? Maybe some example. It's difficult to understand what you're trying with info you provided.

Comment: some code? or demo page?

Comment: Yes, without a live sample I'm afraid we can't really help you. The contents and layout you speak of are just vague terms that don't give us sufficient information with which to provide you a working answer.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it sounds like your side bar has been wrapped in the Index Page block in the customization. Look for `{block:IndexPage}{/block:IndexPage}`. Are those tags surrounding any part of your side bar customization? They could be anywhere in the code (HTML, CSS, or JS.) If so, you need to remove them if you want the side bar to show on all your pages. Otherwise, unless you provide some sample code, I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: ok I guess you are close to the answer as the side bar was actually wrapped inside that block. Anyway although I have removed it the sidebar is still not depicted in the sub pages

Comment: Are there any other block tags around the sidebar or around the sidebar's CSS?

Comment: the sidebar tag is actually wrapped by the container_inner, container_outer, page_inner, page_outer and body tags

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant, is it contained in any other curly bracket `{block:}` tags. For instance, if it's contained in the `{block:Posts}` tag, it's not going to show up on sub-pages because those are not pages that contain posts.